# How change color of date fo holidays

Tags: c#, wpf

I want highlight holidays. But don't know how change color of calendar item.
I tried to set style for CalendarDayButton

```
<Window x:Class="WorkingCalendar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkingCalendar"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="450" 
    Width="600">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HolidayDaysConverter x:Key="HolidayDaysConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="calendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="20"/>
        
        <!--<Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HolidayDaysConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>-->
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
    
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox>
        <Calendar SelectionMode="MultipleRange"
                  MinHeight="100"
                  MinWidth="100"
                  CalendarDayButtonStyle="{StaticResource calendarDayButtonStyle}">
            
            
        </Calendar>
    </Viewbox>
    
</Grid>
```

I can change fontsize, but FiregroundColor does not change. Why?
And how change Foreground?

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

Because the `Foreground` is hardcoded to `#FFBADDE9` in the default template.

> And how change Foreground?

Create your own custom template by copying the default one into your XAML markup and then change the value `Foreground` property. Your `Style` would then look like this:

```
<Style x:Key="calendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Active"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" To="#FF777777" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RegularDay"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Today">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BlackoutDayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDay"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BlackoutDay">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Blackout" To=".2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" Fill="#FFAAAAAA" Opacity="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,1,5,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Path x:Name="Blackout" Data="M8.1772461,11.029181 L10.433105,11.029181 L11.700684,12.801641 L12.973633,11.029181 L15.191895,11.029181 L12.844727,13.999395 L15.21875,17.060919 L12.962891,17.060919 L11.673828,15.256231 L10.352539,17.060919 L8.1396484,17.060919 L10.519043,14.042364 z" Fill="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DayButtonFocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="#FF45D6FA" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!--<Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HolidayDaysConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>-->
</Style>
```